# Install grub raid1 & lvm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, raid, grub

I have installed an Ubuntu Linux on a machine where there was a RHEL (from Dell)

At the end of the installation I got a message that GRUB2 could not be installed. So I booted into a Live Linux (from USB) in order to reinstall GRUB afterwards - following lots of suggestions found on the internet. None helps.

My setup are two 1TB disks with a RAID1 configuration. And the partitions can be seen below. *I think* due to the  the RAID1 setup, the /dev/sda5 has 3 subpartitions which I used for the installation as follows:

- **/** mounted to /dev/mapper/rhel-root as xfs journaling system
- **/home/** mounted to /dev/mapper/rhel-home as xfs journaling system
- **swap** is mounted at /dev/mapper/rhel-swap

I am at my wits end - where should GRUB be installed in the first place? And how will I achieve this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Further details:

- The output of my *sudo fdisk -l* can be found here: http://pastebin.com/BUJuUyUq
- Also, I switched from UEFI to Legacy booting
- And lastly a screenshot of gparted ;-)

[image]

Comment: What partition table are you using?

Comment: Also, did you configure partitions manually while installing ubuntu?

Comment: No, I left the partitions as they were, @khajvah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is hard to understand exactly what is the cause of your problem, I will take a guess.
I guess, you are using [GPT partition scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table), as your hard drive is pretty large and it used to be UEFI based.

Check [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GUID_Partition_Table#BIOS_systems) out. And a quote from the link:

> While GPT support on BIOS systems is theoretically possible it sometimes isn't practical and other times there are complete incompatibilities. Technically the BIOS is only supposed to execute the code on the MBR, therefore leaving the possibility of differing partitioning schemes... However a BIOS may do additional checks including: checking a MBR's integrity, and possibly even for a MBR partition table (though usually only the first partition). If this is a case, a number of workarounds exist that may be able to repair the problem (listed below).

You have a few solutions:

1. Delete everything and use MBR table (this will delete all your files). According to google, it does support 2TB hard drives.
2. Try to get it work with GPT([here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#GUID_Partition_Table_.28GPT.29_specific_instructions) is a link for that). Basically, you need an additional partition and maybe some more hacks.
3. Enable UEFI and use UEFI-based system (I would choose this).

Comment: Ok, thanks I will go trhough this and try to understand and act accordingly.  First things first, MBR, GPT and UEFI are three different approaches to tell the computer where to boot?

Comment: @dmeu [UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) is a replacement to BIOS. MBR and GPT are partitioning schemes. They kind of store information about partitions (so the booting depends on it). For UEFI based systems, GPT partitioning scheme is required. GPT is actually part of UEFI specifications.

Comment: For non-UEFI systems, GPT is supported but you need an [additional partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_boot_partition) and (maybe) some additional stuff(unfortunately I don't have any experience in this).

Comment: I am surprised ubuntu didn't deal with this or at least tell you about the issues with GPT/BIOS.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the info. Yes, I am also a bit angry that it wouldnt complain if a boot-partition is missing. It was first on UEFI, but it clearly failed to add itself to the UEFI partition in this case. I try now in 'legacy' mode and see what I can do

Comment: @dmeu On UEFI mode, you don't need an additional partition. In your question, you said that you have switched to legacy mode. On BIOS(legacy) mode you do need an additional partition.

Comment: Hi @khajvah, yes I figured that out trough your links, and added an EF02 (8Mbit), biosboot partition as sda6 (at the fourth position on disk on the gparted screenshot. I re-installed Ubuntu and this time there was no error. Nevertheless, when restarting the machine, I get the message: "no boot device found·

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23980/discussion-between-khajvah-and-dmeu).